# Integrating elements of list into list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want to integrate items of my list `numbers`:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

into my list of lists `letters`:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'], ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']]
```

To generate a combination of the two, where the first element of `numbers` is added to the front of the first list in `letters` as shown:

```
[['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['2', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['3', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'], ['4', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'], ['5', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']]
```

I've tried to do this using

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    newlist.append ([numbers[i], letters[i]])
```

However, this generates an outcome like this:

```
[['1', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], ['2', ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']], ['3', ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']], ['4', ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']], ['5', ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just combine the lists instead of making them into a new list. I think this is the most pythonic way, and happens to also be the most effecient:

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    newlist.append ([numbers[i]] + letters[i])
```

`435 ns ± 5.89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comparing other answers:

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    newlist.append([numbers[i], *letters[i]])
```

`1.72 µs ± 301 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

and

`combo = [[n, *l] for n, l in zip(numbers, letters)]`
`1.04 µs ± 36.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

all of these return:

```
[['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['2', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
 ['3', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'],
 ['4', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'],
 ['5', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']]
```

Comment: This works, but now each list is encased by double square brackets, how can I remove one of these pairs?

Comment: Edited out a second set of brackets. please try again

Answer (score 2):

One liner using `operator.iconcat`:

```
map(iconcat, map(list, numbers), letters)
```

May not be pretty to some but sure is neat!

---

Other functional solutions I found using `itertools.starmap` and `operator.iadd`:

```
starmap(iadd, zip(map(list, numbers), letters))
```

You can also use: `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
map(chain.from_iterable, zip(numbers, letters)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the sub-lists from `letters` when forming a new list:

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    newlist.append([numbers[i], *letters[i]])
```

Comment: I get this error message: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`

Comment: Did you miss the comma?

Comment: A syntax error means you're using an earlier Python version. The generic unpacking was only made available since Python 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I'm using python 2.7 (I have to for a class) so that would be it

Comment: @wilberox - tell your teacher that Python 2.7 end of life is Jan 1, 2020 so it might be a good idea for the school to adopt a Python version into the curriculum that will still be supported when your class ends.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the lists and then unpack the letter sublist to combine it with the number element.

```
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
letters = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'], ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']]

combo = [[n, *l] for n, l in zip(numbers, letters)]
print(combo)
# [['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['2', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['3', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'], ['4', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'], ['5', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']]
```